# php pdo submit form no reload & hide <a class

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to code a daily gift system based on users table with field dailyg = 0. After they click submit it adds item to users inventory and makes dailyg = 1 and if u close page and reopen it doesnt show anymore which was my plan. but i want to submit and hide the a class button that user clicks to open the form. without reloading page. also trying to see what i can do about user manually reloading page inserting data twice? this is what i have...

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(".trigger_popup_fricc").click(function(){
       $('.dialog').show();
    });
    $('.close').click(function(){
        $('.dialog').hide();
    });
});
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("submit").click(function() {
       $('#trigger_popup_fricc').removeClass('hidden');
       $('#hc-window').removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

```
if($account->GetYourInfos($_SESSION['id'], 'dailyg') <= 0) :


echo '
<a class="trigger_popup_fricc" style="z-index:9999;position:fixed;width:60px;height:66px;margin-top:360px;"></a>
';
endif;
```

```
<div class="dialog" id="hc-window" style="display:none;">
  <div class="title"><a class="close"></a>Daily Gifts</div>
  <div id="hc-window-rag"></div>
  <h1>Claim your daily crackable box</h1>
  <div id="hc-window-benefits">
    <div id="hc-window-benefits-image"></div>
    <span><h1>Daily</h1><p>Each day you get to claim a crackable gift!</p></span>
    <span><h1>Gifts</h1><p>Could be coins, diamonds, a rare?!</p></span></div>
```

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
   $bdd7 = $pdo->query('INSERT INTO items (user_id, room_id, item_id, wall_pos, x, y, z, rot, extra_data, wired_data, limited_data, guild_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [$account->GetYourInfos($_SESSION['id'], 'id'), "0", "9085566", "0", "0", "0", "0.000000", "0", "", "", "0:0", "0"]);
 $bdd7 = $pdo->query('INSERT INTO items (user_id, room_id, item_id, wall_pos, x, y, z, rot, extra_data, wired_data, limited_data, guild_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [$account->GetYourInfos($_SESSION['id'], 'id'), "0", "4025566", "0", "0", "0", "0.000000", "0", "", "", "0:0", "0"]);
   $bdd4 = $pdo->query('UPDATE users SET dailyg = ? WHERE id = ?', [1, $_SESSION['id']]);
}
```

```
            <div id="hc-window-bean">
                <h1>Claim Daily Box</h1>
                <div>
                    <form method="POST" id="form" name="form"><input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit"  value="Claim" class="button green"/></form>
                    <span id="hc-window-bean-credits">25 <img src="http://playforce.me/test/assets/images/hotelview/hcWindow/credit.png"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Any ideas how I can submit and hide the class trigger_popup_fricc without reloading page?? ive been trying all night haha